# Speed Up Moving data from Oracle 11 to MySQL using MS Access

Tags: mysql, vba, oracle, ms-access, oracle11g

I have a little problem with downloading data from Oracle DB and moving it to the MySQL table.

On Oracle i have only a read privilege. The only task I could execute is Select.
On MySQL i have select/insert/update privilege. Also, there's no problem to change anything in mysql structure - i also have access to mysql root.

Each week I have to download huge amount of data from Oracle and move it to MySQL (for further processing). **The best (and the only) solution in my case is to use MS Access.**

My vba code snippet looks like (code is usually put into a loop, where I perform some inserts, each for different business site. Executing it in one query sometimes meet no end).

```vb
Public Sub DownloadData()
On Error GoTo ErrorTrans
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    Dim strWhere1 As String, strWhere2 As String, strQueryName As String
    Dim qdDaneObrRabE As QueryDef, qdDaneObrRabTmp As QueryDef
    Dim cnADO As ADODB.Connection

    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qryDaneObrRabCzysc") 'Calling truncate data procedure on mysql table

    Set cnADO = CurrentProject.Connection
    cnADO.CommandTimeout = 300 '5 minut

    Set qdDaneObrRabE = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryDaneObrRabE")

    strQueryName = "tmpObroty_" & GenerateHash(8)
    Set qdDaneObrRabTmp = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(strQueryName, "select * from table2;") 'this select is just dummy statement, replaced some lines below
    qdDaneObrRabTmp.Connect = qdDaneObrRabE.Connect

    qdDaneObrRabTmp.SQL = Replace(qdDaneObrRabE.SQL, "{WHERE1}", strWhere1)
    qdDaneObrRabTmp.SQL = Replace(qdDaneObrRabTmp.SQL, "{WHERE2}", strWhere2)

    cnADO.Execute "INSERT INTO mysqltable SELECT * FROM " & strQueryName & ";"

    Call QueryDefsCleanUp("tmpObroty_")

    Call MsgBox("Success")
    Set cnADO = Nothing

    Exit Sub
ErrorTrans:
    Call ActivityLog(Environ("USERNAME"), Now, "DownloadData", True, Err.Number, Err.Description)
End Sub
```

**Please let me know if executing these types of inserts via ADODB is good. 
I also tested DAO but i don't see difference.**

**All of used tables/querydefs are linked tables or pass-through querydefs.**

Comment: Eh... Why would there be a difference between ADODB and DAO? If you're using the Access database engine, that doesn't matter. If you want speed, take Access out of the equation and use the FEDERATED storage engine to query the Oracle tables directly from MySQL.

Comment: [Talend open studio for data integration](https://www.talend.com/products/data-integration/data-integration-open-studio/) is good for such operations.

Comment: For now I have NO opportunity to change the way of transfer data. It has to be MS Access. I know it's a bit slow, but i think it could be faster.